# Is "the face that launched a thousand ships" often used parodied or can I use it in a sincere/earnest way?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, expressions

I came across the expression **"the face that launched a thousand ships"** that describes a heavenly beautiful woman but at then end of [this web page](https://grammarist.com/phrase/the-face-that-launched-a-thousand-ships/), it says "The term is also often parodied":

> Today, the face that launched a thousand ships is still most often used to describe the unsurpassed beauty of Helen of Troy, though it may be used to describe the beauty of any woman. **The term is also often parodied.**

So my question is: **Can I use this expression to describe a female in a more sincere/earnest way, rather than in a mocking/joking way?**

BTW: [This comment in another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/187672/a-voice-that-bored-a-thousand-ships-into-sinking-themselves#comment371341_187899) seems to suggest that this expression is mostly used in a joking way:

> A related joke is the dictionary definition "Millihelen: Unit of beauty sufficient to launch one ship".

Comment: Because of the parodies you would need to take particular care that it is understood seriously.

Comment: Marlowe coined the expression with particular reference to the character Helen of Troy (because her elopement was the cause of the Trojan War). Obviously, a woman's beauty doesn't normally cause ships to be launched, so you would have to be careful how you expressed yourself if you were using it seriously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are describing Helen of Troy.  or you are making a particular poetic analogy between this woman and Helen, then you can't really quote this phrase.  It would sound odd to hear a conversation.

> I heard John's new girlfriend is very beautiful.
>
> Yes she has a face that would launch a thousand ships.

It is too poetic for such prosaic use.

If you are writing a Valentine's day card, or song lyrics etc, then maybe.  B